# Condition on strict date much slower than date interval with extract

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, optimization

I have two queryset that gathers me the same result but in which I use different methods in order to look at a specific month for a specific year.

In the first case, I'm using the whole date itself with the day at '01', in the second case I'm using `BETWEEN` in order to subselect the year and `EXTRACT` for the month.

In my first scenario, the queryset takes more than 2mn in order to execute whereas in the second case the queryset executes almost immediatly.

Here the relative queries:

**1st case**

```
SELECT [lot of fields]
FROM "dsn_consolidationcontrat" 
INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationindividu" ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."individu_id" = "dsn_consolidationindividu"."id") 
INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationetablissement" ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."etablissement_id" = "dsn_consolidationetablissement"."id") 
INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationentreprise" ON ("dsn_consolidationetablissement"."entreprise_id" = "dsn_consolidationentreprise"."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dsn_consolidationcontrat" T5 ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."contrat_precedent_id" = T5."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dsn_consolidationcontratfin" ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" = "dsn_consolidationcontratfin"."contrat_id") 
WHERE ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" IN (
    SELECT U0."consolide_id" FROM "dsn_historiquecontrat" U0 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_declaration" U1 ON (U0."declaration_courante_id" = U1."id") 
    WHERE U1."mois" = '2016-12-01'::date) 
AND NOT ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" IN (
    SELECT U2."contrat_id" FROM "dsn_historiquecontratfin" U0 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_declaration" U1 ON (U0."declaration_courante_id" = U1."id") 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationcontratfin" U2 ON (U0."consolide_id" = U2."id") 
    WHERE U1."mois" = '2016-12-01'::date)) 
AND NOT ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" IN (
    SELECT U0."consolide_id" FROM "dsn_historiquecontrat" U0 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_declaration" U1 ON (U0."declaration_courante_id" = U1."id") 
    WHERE (U1."mois" = '2017-01-01'::date AND U0."declaration_precedente_id" IS NOT NULL)))) 
LIMIT 10
```

**2nd case**

```
SELECT [lot of fields]
FROM "dsn_consolidationcontrat" 
INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationindividu" ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."individu_id" = "dsn_consolidationindividu"."id") 
INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationetablissement" ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."etablissement_id" = "dsn_consolidationetablissement"."id") 
INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationentreprise" ON ("dsn_consolidationetablissement"."entreprise_id" = "dsn_consolidationentreprise"."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dsn_consolidationcontrat" T5 ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."contrat_precedent_id" = T5."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "dsn_consolidationcontratfin" ON ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" = "dsn_consolidationcontratfin"."contrat_id") 
WHERE ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" IN (
    SELECT U0."consolide_id" FROM "dsn_historiquecontrat" U0 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_declaration" U1 ON (U0."declaration_courante_id" = U1."id") 
    WHERE U1."mois" BETWEEN '2016-01-01'::date AND '2016-12-31'::date AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U1."mois") = 12)) 
AND NOT ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" IN (
    SELECT U2."contrat_id" FROM "dsn_historiquecontratfin" U0 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_declaration" U1 ON (U0."declaration_courante_id" = U1."id") 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_consolidationcontratfin" U2 ON (U0."consolide_id" = U2."id") 
    WHERE (U1."mois" BETWEEN '2016-01-01'::date AND '2016-12-31'::date AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U1."mois") = 12))) 
AND NOT ("dsn_consolidationcontrat"."id" IN (
    SELECT U0."consolide_id" FROM "dsn_historiquecontrat" U0 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_declaration" U1 ON (U0."declaration_courante_id" = U1."id") 
    WHERE (U1."mois" BETWEEN '2017-01-01'::date AND '2017-12-31'::date AND U0."declaration_precedente_id" IS NOT NULL AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U1."mois") = 1)))) 
LIMIT 10
```

The execution plan for the two querysets are very differents of each other: in the first case we got a bunch of hash join followed by unique operations, but in the second case we have a beautiful sequence of nested loops.

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: Can you post the explain plan for both queries? Can you also post the explain plan for the subqueries -- for example, `SELECT U0."consolide_id" FROM "dsn_historiquecontrat" U0 
    INNER JOIN "dsn_declaration" U1 ON (U0."declaration_courante_id" = U1."id") 
    WHERE U1."mois" BETWEEN '2016-01-01'::date AND '2016-12-31'::date AND EXTRACT('month' FROM U1."mois") = 12`

Comment: 1st case : https://explain.depesz.com/s/YbI7 https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWXs0.png

Comment: 2nd case : https://explain.depesz.com/s/6AnR https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXftw.png